# WCF stopped working on IIS 7 after adding new HTTP and HTTPS bindings

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7, wcf-binding

I am using `ASP.NET 3.5` with `C#`. I have a `web-application` that have a `WCF`. I had deployed it on Server with `Bindings HTTP` and `HTTPS`. Everything was working well.

Today I added two more bindings of `HTTP` and `HTTPS` on the same site but `with different host names`. (I have that new domain registered and I already have pointed that with my IP address). And suddenly, the `WCF` for that same site stopped working.

I did it for two sites in `IIS` and both of them are returning exception on `WCF` call, however the `login` and all other pages are working fine.

The ServiceModel part of web.config is as below :

```
     <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webBindingHTTP">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="webBindingHTTPS">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ihrole.service.remoteBehavior">
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="webHttpEnabled">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ihrole.service.remoteBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ihrole.service.remoteBehavior" name="ihrole.service.remote">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ihrole.service.remoteBehavior" bindingConfiguration="webBindingHTTP" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ihrole.service.Iremote" />
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ihrole.service.remoteBehavior" bindingConfiguration="webBindingHTTPS" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ihrole.service.Iremote" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Again, I do have another site hosted on the same `IIS` that is also having `HTTP` and `HTTPS` bindings. But I haven't added the new ones in this site and the `WCF` call is working fine on the same.

Any guess or solution? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Show your Web.config with the <system.ServiceModel> settings

Comment: @FlopScientist I have updated the question with servicemodel settings.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue after adding a certificate, it turns out Skype was using port 443 and IIS wouldn't start. Just something to try..

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to specify that your WCF service can be run on all Bindings for a single website.

In  Asp.Net 3.5, when a website has multiple bindings, you should specify Pass through filters ( adding a base address for the WCF service )  using the `<baseAddressPrefixFilters>` element. See Sample below. [**`MSDN reference here.`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924481%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    ... 
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="http://Testsite2.com:3546"/>
            <add prefix="http://testSite.com:3566"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
   ...
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So, here http://Testsite2.com:3546 and http://testSite.com:3566 are the only base addresses, for their respective schemes, which will be allowed to be passed through, which means simply that WCF service will work for these two addresses. The `baseAddressPrefixFilter` does not support any wildcards .